# Detect change on different inputs using .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following form:

```
<form class="uk-form">
  <label for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
    <input type="text"  id="startDate" data-uk-datepicker="{format:'YYYY-MM-DD'}">
  <label for="endDate">End Date:</label>
    <input type="text"  id="endDate" data-uk-datepicker="{format:'YYYY-MM-DD'}">
</form>
```

What I need is to call a JS function once one of those datapicker gets changed using .on() in JQuery.

I get it to work using only one with this code:

```
$('#startDate').on('change', function() {
```

However what I need is that when one of them changes to run the function, sort of like this:

```
$('#startDate'||'#endDate' ).on('change', function() {
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Issue solved! This is how I did it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15864685/5100770

Comment: Ideally you should do it with a name attribute. However it works with class as well like in the link you shared.

Answer (score 1):

or you can have

```
$("form").on('change', "#startDate, #endDate", function(event){...})
```

So you dont need to worry about replacing the element

Answer (score 1):

To attach change event on more than one element you can use [multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/). Another possibility is to use a [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Inside the event handler, to get the element for which the event is triggered you can use the [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

```js
$(function () {
  // Multiple selector:
  // $('#startDate, #endDate').datepicker();
  // or, class selector:
  $(':text.dpClass').datepicker();
  
  //$('#startDate, #endDate').on('change', function(e) {
  $(':text.dpClass').on('change', function(e) {
    $('#log').text('Changed element is:' + e.target.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p id="log"></p>
<form class="uk-form">
    <label for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
    <input type="text"  id="startDate" class="dpClass" data-uk-datepicker="{format:'YYYY-MM-DD'}">
    <label for="endDate">End Date:</label>
    <input type="text"  id="endDate" class="dpClass" data-uk-datepicker="{format:'YYYY-MM-DD'}">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try: `$('input').on('change', function () {`

Of course if you have more inputs on the page it will fire for them too. So perhaps give both of the pickers unique class and add `on` handler to that class.

Answer (score 0):

Give both the inputs a name. and try this:

```
$("input[name='someName']").on('change', function() {});
```